# Can i use JSP with Angular2?

Tags: angular

I necessary to use JAVA and Angular2. Can i use JSP with Angular2 ?

i got error message

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    ...
    templateUrl: '../views/sidebar.jsp', 
    ...
})
```

sidebar.jsp

```
<li>
    <a href="<c:url value="/logout" />">
         <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> 
         Logout
    </a>
</li>
```

***Error***

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "a" ("></li>
            <li><a href="<c:url value="/logout" />"><i
                    class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout[ERROR ->]</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
"): AppComponent@58:45
```

====================================================================

edited

```
<li><a href="<c:url value="/logout" />">
```

to

```
<li><a href='<c:url value="/logout" />'>
```

however JSTL tag wasn't compile :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSP but the simple answer to your question is yes, you can use JSP with Angular2.  Angular is a frontend framework that will work with any other backend system.  The error you're getting appear to be the result of your web server not processing your JSP page properly and then Angular not being able to parse it.

Comment: i dont know about JSP but yes in angular2 we use `routerLink` instead of `href` , also `<a>` is not an self closing tag as you did. try using this  `<a href="<c:url value='/logout'>">
         <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> 
         Logout
    </a>`, also we can't use  `" "` in between `" " `

Comment: thank all. however JSTL tag wasn't compile :'(

Comment: In my component html, I use jsp via iframes, even though my experience is not good with iframes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes off course we can use JSP with angular2. I don't know much about `JSP` usage with `angular2`, but yes found some mistakes in your code,

1. We can't use `" "` in `" "` we should have to use either `' '` in `" "` or vice versa.
2. In angular2 we use `routerLink` instead of `href`.
3. `<a>` is not self closing tag i think you make it in your code. so throwing error `Unexpected closing tag "a"`