# Angular 2: Using a .jsp file as template for component

Tags: java, angular, jsp, tomcat

I want to use a jsp as a template file for an angular2 component. 
When running the project on angular-cli server I get a compilation error, which is expected:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XtTd.jpg

But then I tried copying the whole project to my tomcat's webapps folder, and the angular code doesnt work (index.html doesnt show the text from app.component, only "loading....").

As you can probably tell, im relatively new to angular2 and programming in general. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: using jsp and angular is not a good idea as both of them are doing same thing (among other things), templating. angular is doing it client side, jsp is doing it in server side. Instead a good approach will be to write REST based web endpoints which angular will consume and use to do client side rendering..

Comment: unfortunately i have to do it this way, but thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

JSP or JavaServerPages is a technology used to process HTML and do server side rendering running Tomcat or another Java enabled web server.

Angular is a client side framework that converts all your code to JavaScript and HTML.

To answer your question, you cannot use JSP pages for Angular templates.

Comment: Please see: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394688/can-i-use-jsp-with-angular2' anyway it is not good practice though.

Comment: @VedantTerkar I don't see any evidence of a mechanism provided to use JSP with Angular in that thread. Those who have answered even mention themselves that they aren't familiar with JSP. The problem with JSP is that each response is built on request, rather than just serving static content. JSP files can't be compiled to HTML. If you want to use JSP in components then you'll need to lazy-load the template content so that it can be generated by the server. *I'd highly recommend against this*, though, unless you have a very good reason to do so.